# CMake : how to create a directory during installation with certain access rights?

Tags: permissions, installation, cmake, access-rights

I have an application that is installed in /opt (this is the way it is done here). 
It is fine to have all the files and folders belonging to root apart from the *logs* directory that must be writable by anyone.

To create the logs directory I do

```
INSTALL(CODE "FILE(MAKE_DIRECTORY \${ENV}\${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/logs)")
```

How can I then chmod the directory ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using the `CODE` variant of the `INSTALL` command, consider using the `DIRECTORY` variant instead. This one lets you specify the file system permissions, i.e.:

```
install (DIRECTORY "Logs" DESTINATION "." DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS 
    OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ OWNER_EXECUTE
    GROUP_WRITE GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE
    WORLD_WRITE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE)
```

For the `install` command to succeed, an empty directory `Logs` must exist in the source folder.

Comment: to create the empty directory logs I do : FILE(MAKE_DIRECTORY logs)
Thank you for your help

Comment: @Barth Alternatively, `DIRECTORY DESTINATION "Logs"` creates the directory `Logs` at installation time without that requirement of `Logs` to exist at all.

Comment: @YSC your variant should be in the accepted answer. The behavior for missing DIRECTORY argument is well [documented](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#directory) in CMake: `If no input directory names are given the destination directory will be created but nothing will be installed into it.`